# Cannot replace special characters in a Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with Python 3.5 in Windows.  I have a dataframe where a `'titles'` str type column contains titles of headlines, some of which have special characters such as `â`,`€`,`˜`.

I am trying to replace these with a space `''` using `pandas.replace`. I have tried various iterations and nothing works. I am able to replace regular characters, but these special characters just don't seem to work.

The code runs without error, but the replacement simply does not occur, and instead the original title is returned.  Below is what I have tried already.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
df['clean_title'] = df['titles'].replace('€','',regex=True)
df['clean_titles'] = df['titles'].replace('€','')
df['clean_titles'] = df['titles'].str.replace('€','')

def clean_text(row):
   return re.sub('€','',str(row))
   return str(row).replace('€','')
df['clean_title'] = df['titles'].apply(clean_text)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce, your third example works for me.  Can you post a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: let's say on title is 'â€˜BetterHashâ€™: Bitcoin Core Dev. Proposes New Protocols to Decentralize Bitcoin Mining'

Comment: This looks more like an encoding error. Therefore you better solve this at the encoding level.

Comment: I have tried various encodings such as utf-8 while importing the csv file using read_csv.  Nothing works :(

Comment: Try `.replace('\xE2\x82\xAC', '')`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it turns out that this was only occurring when I sent the dataframe to csv, and was actually totally fine in python.

Answer (score 4):

We can only assume that you refer to non-ASCI as 'special' characters.

To remove *all* non-ASCI characters in a pandas dataframe column, do the following:

```
df['clean_titles'] = df['titles'].str.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7f]', '')
```

Note that this is a scalable solution as it works for *any* non-ASCI char.

Answer (score 0):

How to remove escape sequence character in dataframe

Data.

product,rating
pest,<br> test
mouse,/
 mousetest

Solution: scala Code

```
 val finaldf = df.withColumn("rating", regexp_replace(col("rating"), "\\\\", "/")).show()
```