# Python: Replace the special character by NULL in each column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID      Date_Loading          Date_delivery       Value
001     01.11.2017             20.11.2017         200.34
002     %^&**##_               15.01.2018         300.05
003     11.12.2018             _%67*              7*7%
```

As we can see that except `ID` column I have special character in all columns.

Objective: To replace those special character by `None`. So the final dataframe should look like:

```
ID      Date_Loading          Date_delivery       Value
001     01.11.2017             20.11.2017         200.34
002     Null                   15.01.2018         300.05
003     11.12.2018             Null               Null
```

Then as a next step I want parse the Date columns to YYYY-MM-DD format.

In order to accomplish this I am using the following code snippet:

```
for c in df.columns.tolist():
  df[c] = df[c].astype(str).str.replace(r"[^A-Za-z0-9]"," ")
df['Date_Loading'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Loading'],error='coerce',format='YYYY-MM-DD')
df['Date_delivery'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Loading'],error='coerce',format='YYYY-MM-DD')
```

But the above code is just not working!!! Even if I am trying to replace, it is not working.

Am I missing out anything?

P.S.: I have tried in SO - > [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50846719/cannot-replace-special-characters-in-a-python-pandas-dataframe) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596529/replacing-special-characters-in-pandas-dataframe) but so far no luck

Comment: There are another columns? If yes, how should be processing? All another columns to numbers?

Comment: @jezrael: just adding `regex=True` in `str.replace` will do the trick. But I need to convert the date fields as I wanted i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: `But I need to convert the date fields as I wanted i.e. YYYY-MM-DD format.` - Not sure if understand now not working?

Comment: yes it is working. Just for my understanding, if I do  a pd.read_csv(file,parse_dates = date_cols), will it do this job as you have explained? I do not care about `Value` field as of now.

Comment: Unfortuantely not only, need custom function, give me a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify fomrat of datetimes of input data, here `DD.MM.YYYY` by `'%d.%m.%Y'` and for convert numbers use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
 #for processing all columns
 df = df.astype(str).replace(r"[^A-Za-z0-9]","", regex=True)

df['Date_Loading'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Loading'],errors='coerce',format='%d.%m.%Y')
df['Date_delivery'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_delivery'],errors='coerce',format='%d.%m.%Y')

df['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Value'],errors='coerce')
print (df)
   ID Date_Loading Date_delivery   Value
0   1   2017-11-01    2017-11-20  200.34
1   2          NaT    2018-01-15  300.05
2   3   2018-12-11           NaT     NaN

print (df.dtypes)
ID                        int64
Date_Loading     datetime64[ns]
Date_delivery    datetime64[ns]
Value                   float64
dtype: object
```

EDIT:

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d.%m.%Y', errors='coerce',)

df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['Date_Loading','Date_delivery'], date_parser=dateparse)
    
print (df)
   ID Date_Loading Date_delivery   Value
0   1   2017-11-01    2017-11-20  200.34
1   2          NaT    2018-01-15  300.05
2   3   2018-12-11           NaT    7*7%
```